# GP Preferences vs folder redirection. Start menu

Tags: performance, redirection, group-policy

We are looking at creating set start menus but unsure if we should use GPP or folder redirection.

We have laptops that are taken off site  so folder redirection would have to be to the C drive on the machine which would mean that every change that we would like to make would also have to be made on all machines.

GPP enables us to target shortcuts to certain machines but the start menu would have to be created on each login to new computers.

Which would be best for speed?  Will the GPP start menu still be available if the users logs on when not connected on the cached profile.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Folder redirection would not work to set a custom menu. You could use mandatory profiles to do that or GP Preferences. My vote would be to use the preferences option.